# Decompile a Java project and compile

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, decompiling

I am trying to [decompile](https://code.google.com/p/innlab/downloads/detail?name=jd-gui-0.3.3.windows.zip&) a java project(.jar) file and I am able to get .java files from it. Now how can I compile it back? I am able to add the .java files to Netbeans just as a single file.But how can I add it as a project add compile it? The project is a JavaFX project. So please help me on this.

Comment: Is it some 3rd party jar? Can you share its name and link. Or is it some internal project ?

Comment: @SaifAsif I can't share the project.It's just a internal project and does not have any copyrights.

Comment: If you are decompiling a jar, you must get the project structure as well ! You can just make a Java Project of the exact structure !

Comment: @ItachiUchiha So should I create and same packages as i got from decompile tool? I dont know much about JavaFX. in the decomiled folder inside a com\qwe\asdff\ddd\ i have folder main . It has .fxml file and for every file it has a controller .java file. I m confused about this.

Comment: @ITresearcher `com\qwe\asdff\ddd` corresponds to the package, which in any IDE, you will see as `com.qwe.asdff.ddd` inside which you can create the corresponding `.fxml` and `.java` files

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Yes. But does that main folder is also a package?

Comment: I haven't seen your folder structure, but taking a guess, the main folder you are talking about must be the `source/src` folder

Comment: @ItachiUchiha main folder is present inside about 3 packages. So does it really a package called main or something else?In one of the code there is line like package com.qwe.asdff.ddd.main  So it shud be a package i think?

Comment: yes, its pretty obvious..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, but I don't think you will be able to import the project inside the jar just out of the box ( in this case, out-of-the-jar ) like that.

We can use the most basic technique ( a bit dirty I admit ) but it works.

1. Extract the contents of the jar in a directory and decompile it like you done it before
2. Next, make an empty project inside netbeans ( with no src directory or anything )
3. Copy the contents of your decompiled project into this netbeans folder. You should now see a skeleton structure of some files. *Note* The poject is inisde netbeans but it is not a java project yet.
4. Edit the classpath of the netbeans project and add java library to make it into a Java netbeans project.

The other technique that I use sometimes is that I make all the project files required by the IDE (Eclipse in my case) manually and then tell eclipse to import the project. When eclipse finds all the required files ( .project, .classpath and all ), it imports into the IDE just fine

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a JavaFX project in your IDE.
2. Decompile the jar to get the java files. The files will be places in
   different folders and sub folders based on the packaging.
3. Put the folders as packages in the project created in step 1 above.
4. Clean and compile the project in your IDE.

P.S: Make sure you respect the license agreements if you are planning the use the decompiled and recompiled classes in your project.

Comment: I dont know much about JavaFX. in the decomiled folder inside a com\qwe\asdff\ddd\ i have folder main . It has .fxml file and for every file it has a controller .java file. I m confused about this

Comment: Yeah... first you need to check how to do a hello world in JavaFX in netbeans. Once your hello world project is setup, you will automatically figure where to place the java and fxml files

Comment: Ok.I will try and get back to you.

Comment: I am getting lot of errors. Some errors are duplicate declaration of variable. And also errors like "anonymous class implements interface; cannot have arguments" for the code private static void showFallback(boolean jreError) {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(jreError) { private final boolean val$jreError;

Comment: That's not surprising.  No Java decompiler is going to give you error-free code all of the time, or even most of the time.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I didn't get what you trying to say? Do u mean java decompilers won't decompile properly??

Comment: @ITresearcher I'm saying that decompilers do not always produce correct results, and it is not possible for them to always produce correct results.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Ok. I got it. Your precious comments was confusing!!

Comment: @ITresearcher The jist of my advice is: do not assume that the decompiler has given you accurate results, even if the results compile.  Decompilers should be used for analysis, not for providing production-ready code.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yes. I am using it just for analysis.

Comment: @ITresearcher was your question answered? Are you looking for anything else?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no guarantee that a decompiled code will recompile.
This project https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-core has recompilation as part of its test suite on a few set of open-source projects, and this fork https://github.com/nbauma109/jd-core continues in this direction, but each new project and version requires additional work to get the recompilation right.

The GUI part of the same projects are respectively:

- https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui
- https://github.com/nbauma109/jd-gui-duo