# Extract JavaFX source code from JAR file?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-1

I want to extract the source code of our project from .jar file which uses .java and .fx(Javafx). We use Javafx for frontend design. When i extract using JavaDecompiler tools , the .java files are correctly showing but .fx (javafx) files are not showing exactly as our source code.

For example, I decompiled our .jar file it showed the .fx class as follows :

```
   ......
   if ((this.VFLG$panelW & 0x5) == 4)

   {

     this.VFLG$panelW = ((short)varFlags$);return varNewValue$;

   }

   return this.$panelW;
  }
  .....
```

Comment: why do you want this ? have you lost your source code ?!!

Comment: We don't have the source code of that particular project.Yes, we have backup that may or maynot be correct as same.So, i tried to extract the source code from .jar file which is available to us.

Comment: You might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670227/decompile-a-java-project-and-compile